# Can a CASE expression have 2 resultant values

Tags: sql, case

I have to write a case expression in SQL which goes like this,

case condition

```
if (T_CD = 'Y')                         
        Case C_CD = 'H3' 
        set R_ID = 3 and RS_ID = 25                 
        CASE A_FLG = 'N' and Mod  =  'D'
        set R_ID = 3 and RS_ID = 31
```

Both R_ID and RS_ID populate columns in a different table and have to be derived as per condition above.

My question is - Since I want 2 separate fields out of my case expression, will a single Case give out 2 resultant field values for me. Or Do I have to write 2 different case expressions for it.

Comment: No.   Like all expressions in SQL, a `case` statement only returns one value.

Comment: Thanks muh for the response

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms supports row types, maybe this works for you:

```
select case when a = 1 then (1,2) else (3,4) end from testtable;
```

The [SQL Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml) says:

```
The following feature outside Core SQL-2003 is used:

T051, "Row types"
```